# Elementary schools summation in denominator?

Tags: fractions, elementary-functions

after being lazy for a long time and being away from any fraction and equations, I am confused with a seriously ridiculous math problem, and I want to confirm my answer:

the equation is pretty simple as I followed some formula and having something like this:

$\frac{100}{100+2}=?$
is this the right answer?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZEpxD.png)

Or did I just failed in my exam?

By the way, I know its probably the simplest and the dumbest question ever, so if that's what you think forgive me.

Comment: Think about this logically: If you consider the number $100/102$, it has to be pretty close to one, right? I mean, 100 is pretty close to 102. But 1/3 is not close to 1. Therefore, intuitively, this cannot be correct.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: The thing to learn from this: You cannot cancel terms that are summed together in fractions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplifying fractions involves **only multiplication, not summation**. For example, if you have a fraction
$$
\frac{100}{102}
$$
and you need to simplify it, you multiply both the enumerator and denominator with the same number (Why the same number? because their ratio is exactly 1, and multiplying by 1 doesn't change the value of a number). In this case, we can multiply both by $1/2$:
$$
\frac{100}{102} \times \frac{1/2}{1/2} = \frac{(100/2)}{(102/2)} = \frac{50}{51}
$$
This is as far as we can simplify this fraction (Why? Because $50= 2\times 5^2$  and $51= 3\times 17$, and we see that they don't have any common factors).

**This is all that you can do to a fraction. Don't cancel summed terms in a fraction.**

Comment: OK, guess that exam as a fail then :((, damn (thanks by the way)